# Django, Ubuntu-server, Nginx, Gunicorn Server Error 500

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx, gunicorn, ubuntu-server

The issue I am having currently is that after I have launched my project with Gunicorn and do a symbolical link to Nginx’s sites-available to sites-enabled directory, followed with the shell command ... sudo service nginx reload … I’m given an error page html that says “ Server Error 500” when I attempt to connect locally and the project isn’t even talking to the outside world seeing as my domain is a blank canvas.  I’m at a lost as to whether this error lies in my Nginx, Gunicorn, or Django.  Any help, tips or good criticism will be gladly welcomed.

Project specifics:

This is being lauched off a small pc I built at home as a way to test the waters for different web ideas I have, by testing their potential locally first I can decide as to whether or not they're valuable.

Python 3.4

Virtualenv latest

Django 1.8

Gunicorn latest

Nginx latest

Ubuntu server 14.04.4 LTS

DB type: sqlite3(I have a very html based project)

#### settings.py

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*",]
```

#### wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "gartp.settings"

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

#### start_gunicorn.bash

#### this file has been … chmod +x … to make it excutable and is lauched with ./start_gunicorn.bash

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

LOGFILE=/home/workarea/gart/gartp/gartp.log

ERRORFILE=/home/workarea/gart/gartp/error.log

LOGDIR=$(dirname $LOGFILE)

NUM_WORKERS=4

#The below address:port info will be used later to configure Nginx with Gunicorn

ADDRESS=127.0.0.1:8002

# user/group to run as

#USER=your_unix_user

#GROUP=your_unix_group

cd /home/workarea/gart/gartp/

source /home/workarea/gart/bin/activate

test -d $LOGDIR || mkdir -p $LOGDIR

exec /home/workarea/gart/bin/gunicorn -w $NUM_WORKERS --bind=$ADDRESS gartp.wsgi \

--log-level=debug \

--log-file=$LOGFILE 2>>$LOGFILE  1>>$ERRORFILE  &
```

#### nginx sites-available file ‘gartp’

#### linked with … sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject /etc/nginx/sites-enabled...

```
upstream app_server_djangoapp {
    server localhost:8002 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    #EC2 instance security group must be configured to accept http  connections over Port 80
listen 80;
server_name mydomain.com; # changed for a touch of privacy
#server_name ec2;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/guni-access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/guni-error.log info;

keepalive_timeout 5;

# path for static files
root /home/workarea/gart/gartp/task/static;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://app_server_djangoapp;
        break;
    }
}
```

}

#### nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
     ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gartp;
```

}

#### static ip configuration, values are not my own but from the example I used.  I should state as well that I use a NIC on this pc.

#### /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static 
address 192.168.1.128 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
network 192.168.1.0 
broadcast 192.168.1.255 
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

#### /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base

```
search  (domain name) 
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Your first step in case of server error 500 should be to run your application with `DEBUG = True` - in most cases there should be some useful info.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks for the reminder.  I should have stated my noob status at the begining of this post but like usual I forgot lol.

Comment: That did the trick rafalmp!  Turns out my django templates setup was referencing an old directory path, a quick settings.py visit and it's accessible.  Now I just have to figure out what I did wrong to eliminate all my css and how to get it talking through my dd-wrt router to my domain naming service and I will be in good shape!  Thanks so much!!

Comment: @pleasantfoil just FYI if that hadn't worked there are log files for both gunicorn and nginx that usually point you in the right direction as to what is going wrong (and are good to post when you're asking a question to do with your server config issues).

Comment: @YPCrumble Thanks for the future advice.  I'll be sure to include those when I need help with gunicorn and nginx.

Comment: Just case anyone was wondering where the log files for an Ubuntu server, nginx keeps them in /var/log/nginx by default.